# NodeJS app deploying with PM2 (both clustered and not)

Tags: node.js, pm2

Let's assume the following flow:

1. /project on server has a **scoped** pm2 instance running
2. new app version is pushed to master
3. CI builds the new version

How do I let CI deploy the new app instance to x machines?

Current idea:
4. CI transfer the build to /project-next on server
5. CI stops scoped pm2 on /project and starts scoped pm2 on /project-next
6. CI moves /project-next to /project

But step 5 will result in broken app: how can I manage to have a graceful pm2 deployment without downtime?

Associated github issue: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a form of blue/green deployments?

Basically, you have two foldlers: project-a and project-b. Assuming your production is running on project-a, you deploy the next version in project-b, start it, run CI tests on it. Then, once everything is up and running, you start directing request to project-b (using a loadbalancer, iptables rules or whatever)

Now you can stop project-a (the old version) and that's it you deployed with zero downtime.

On the next deploy, you move new version on project-a, then do the exact same process the other way around (run in project a, redirect project-b to project-a, kill project-b)

Comment: interesting! downsides: 1) only half of machines will be working at any time? 2) how to have the same working with single machine infrastructure? because with one server I don't have the chance to stop the serving on x:80

Comment: The key with nodejs is to make it listen on some non privillegied port (>1024). This way you can run multiple node instances on the same machine (so project-a and b run at the same time on the same machine). The key is to have some load balancer (like an nginx) on port 80 that do the request forwarding. Btw it's a bad thing security wise to have a nodejs directly facing public network IMO.

Comment: why is a bad practices? node always run under unprivileged user!

Comment: good call on different ports anyway: I could have every server serving different app versions

Comment: In the last comment you sayd it was a single machine infrastructure and now we are tackling with a multi machine infrastructure?
Any way it's up to what you do during deployment and I don't really see the problem here. If you don't deploy the same version to every server, then of course you'll have different versions across serveurs. But if you make sure every server get the new version before doing the switch between A or B, then you'll have the exact same version everywhere everytime...

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! My goal is to have a good architecture that I can apply with the less effort possible to both a single-machine and multi-machine environment. In the former (case A, 3 clients with this right now) I won't have load balancers and just 1 server bound to :80, in the latter (case B, 2 clients with this right now) I will have a load balancer and multiple servers.

Comment: If you really want both, then go directly for the loadbalancer + X node servers. Both of them can run on the same machine plus you can add another node server on the fly without changing your architecture plus nginx impact is negligible. Also you get things like virtual host and direct streaming of assets directly from nginx, free of code, and more performant at that than your nodejs server.